# How to Read contents of Windows Event Log Using Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is there a class or function which allows you to read the Windows event log.  This is the log you see when you open  **eventvwr.msc**.  And ideally select a specific log (in my case the **Applications** log under **Windows Log**), and place filters on date and source.

Comment: @RBA That question is unrelated. That concerns logging rather than reading the contents of the log.

Comment: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-event-logs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`Win32_NTLogEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class to read the contents of the Windows Log.

Try this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  GetLogEvents;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Category,ComputerName,EventCode,Message,RecordNumber FROM Win32_NTLogEvent  Where Logfile="System"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Category          %s',[String(FWbemObject.Category)]));
    Writeln(Format('Computer Name     %s',[String(FWbemObject.ComputerName)]));
    Writeln(Format('EventCode         %d',[Integer(FWbemObject.EventCode)]));
    Writeln(Format('Message           %s',[String(FWbemObject.Message)]));
    Writeln(Format('RecordNumber      %d',[Integer(FWbemObject.RecordNumber)]));
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetLogEvents;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

For more samples try this blog entry [`WMI Tasks using Delphi – Event Logs`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-event-logs/)

Comment: Isn't WMI too slow and resource consuming for this task? Also your code depends on WMI. My personal experience in corp environments shows that WMI may be broken for any reason. Anyway - your code is ok, but I would prefer to use native APIs :)

Comment: The WMI speed depend of many factors, you can improve a lot the performance of the WMI filtering the WQL expression properly (using the `where` sentence), retrieving only the fields to use , re-utilizing the WMI connection and using the WMI COM API.

Comment: Ok - I got this to work.  But I am finding FWbemObject.Message is always null.  So I can't get the textual message.

Answer (score 3):

Reading an event log is done with the [`ReadEventLog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363674.aspx) function.  See MSDN for an example:

[Querying for Event Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) includes a component named `JvNTEventLog` which can open and manipulate Windows Event Log.

Comment: JVCL does not work with the new EvtLog API, as such can't request any Custom Event Logs