# WMI doesn't return any results

Tags: delphi, wmi

When I use WMI without a `where` clause, it can return some results. But when I use it with a `where` clause, it doesn't return any results. For example, my events log has eventcode 4798, but WMI doesn't return it.

```
procedure GetLogEvents(domain, user, password: string; Proc: TEventLogResultProc);
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  i             : integer;
  Res: TEventLog;
begin;
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
    try
      FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(domain, 'root\CIMV2', user, password);
    except
      FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
    end;
    FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Category,'+
                                                  ' ComputerName,'+
                                                  ' EventCode,'+
                                                  ' Message,'+
                                                  ' RecordNumber,'+
                                                  ' EventType,'+
                                                  ' TimeGenerated,'+
                                                  ' TimeWritten,'+
                                                  ' User,'+
                                                  ' Type,'+
                                                  ' EventIdentifier,'+
                                                  ' SourceName FROM Win32_NTLogEvent '+
                                                  ' Where EventCode="4798" or EventCode="5140" or EventCode="5142" '+
                                                  ' or EventCode="5143" or EventCode="5144" or ' +
                                                  ' EventCode="4663" or EventCode="4659" or EventCode="4656" or EventCode="4907" '+
                                                  ' or EventCode="4663" or EventCode="4660" or EventCode="4670"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
    oEnum := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
      try Res.Category        := String(FWbemObject.Category); except end;
      try Res.ComputerName    := String(FWbemObject.ComputerName); except end;
      try Res.sMessage        := String(FWbemObject.Message); except end;
      try Res.RecordNumber    := Integer(FWbemObject.RecordNumber); except end;
      try Res.EventCode       := Integer(FWbemObject.EventCode); except end;
      try Res.EventType       := String(FWbemObject.EventType); except end;
      try Res.TimeGenerated   := String(FWbemObject.TimeGenerated); except end;
      try Res.TimeWritten     := String(FWbemObject.TimeWritten); except end;
      try Res.SourceName      := String(FWbemObject.SourceName); except end;

      try Res.User            := String(FWbemObject.User); except end;
      try Res.sType           := String(FWbemObject.Type); except end;
      try Res.EventIdentifier := String(FWbemObject.EventIdentifier); except end;
      Proc(Res);
      FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `EventCode` is a `uint16`, so why are you querying it as if it were a `string`? Drop the quote characters around the eventcode values you are interested in: `... Where EventCode=4798 or EventCode=5140 or ...`

Comment: still doesn't work @RemyLebeau

Comment: Have a look at this neat tool - [WMI Delphi Code Creator (WDCC)](https://github.com/RRUZ/wmi-delphi-code-creator). Maybe it already covers the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Security events aren't available to every process. Check security settings. A quick check would be to make sure that without the WHERE events with the specific eventcodes you are looking for are showing up.

Comment: Might be easier to develop and test your WMI query in [WBEMTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/develop/core/understand/introduction-to-wbemtest).

Comment: it returns unspecified error from now

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13142015/5042682) worked, added `NullStrictConvert := False;`  to bypass all that TryE.

Comment: from now wmi doesn't return if data result is big then 2400 records :( how to solve that please help.